# inotifywatch: continue watch after file rotation

Tags: logrotate, inotify

I'm trying to write a script that uses `inotifywatch` to watch for changes in a log file. If a specific message is written to the log file, it's supposed to trigger a certain function. The script currently exists in this basic form:

```
while inotifywait -e modify /var/log/auth.log
do
  alert=$(tail -n1 /var/log/auth.log | grep -E -o ".{0,7}password")
  if [[ $alert == "Failed password" ]]
  then
   echo "FAILURE" >> test.log
  elif [[ $alert == "cepted password" ]]
  then
   echo "LOGIN" >> test.log
  fi
done
```

Everything works fine – up until the point where the logfile watched by `inotifywatch` is **rotated**. Then it ceases to function. I presume that's because during rotation the watched file is renamed and no longer written to afterwards and a new file with the old name is created in its place which `inotify` has never been told to watch in the first place.

I tried to circumvent this by switching from `inotifywatch` to using `tail -f` but the same problem seems to apply there as well.

Now I realize this could probably be solved by creating a huge `if`-structure in which `inotifywatch` not only watches for `modify`, but also for file creation and restarts a watch for modification. But I like to keep things simple, so does anyone know if there's a simpler way? (And please, no, I don't want to use prefabricated solutions like fail2ban etc. – the interesting part for me is to create stuff like this myself with simple tools.)

Comment: if your tail command supports `-F` it should do what you want.

Answer (score 6):

`inotify` is used to monitor files an directory by their inode, not by their name. When the file is rotated, its content does not change any longer (except for a short period, until the daemons are reloaded so that they use the newly created log file)

AFAIK, `tail -f` uses the inotify system, so it won't help. But if you have a working solution with `tail -f` then use `tail --follow=name` (or `tail -F`) if this is supported by your version of `tail` (POSIX tail does not support this). `tail` will then monitor the file identified by its filename. Here is an excerpt of the man page:

> With --follow (-f), tail defaults to following the file descriptor, which
>   means that even if a tail'ed file is renamed, tail will  con‐ tinue to
>   track its end.  This default behavior is not desirable when you really want
>   to track the actual name of the file, not the file descriptor (e.g., log
>   rotation).  Use --follow=name in that case.  That causes tail to track the
>   named file in a way that  accommodates renaming, removal and creation.

[update]

Example of use:

```
tail -n0 -F my_file.log \
| while read -r log_line; do
    do_something_with "$log_line"
done
```

Because of the pipe, the while loop executes in a sub-process, which may cause you troubles if you want to modify variables outside the loop. If you use `bash`, you may want to use this alternative syntax which does not have this undesirable effect (but is less readable):

```
while read -r log_line; do
    do_something_with "$log_line"
done < <(tail -n0 -F my_file.log)
```

Comment: Very simple and nice solution, thanks! Do you also happen to know how to build that into a `while`-loop so that `do ... done` will only be triggered once per new line of the followed file?

Comment: @Nick I have amended my answer to add such an example.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with *inotifywait* with a one-liner:

```
inotifywait -e move_self -e modify -m /path/to/some/file | awk '$2=="MODIFY" {system("/bin/echo Yes")}'
```

The *-m* flag keeps monitoring the file indefinitely, for the events *move_self* (which allows monitoring the name change of a file or directory) and *modify*, passing the output to an *awk* command which weeds out *move_self* events, executing the command inside the *system* set of parentheses for every *modify* event. You will have to write your own shell script in lieu of my *echo* command. Please pay attention to the various sets of apostrophes and quotation marks.

Comment: Intersting idea! But in my current experiments this - when first started - does not `do your stuff`, because `move_self` is not triggered until the first rotation takes place. Afterwards, it establishes a watch but only again for `move_self` and still doesn't watch for modify. Not sure why, because your code would indicate otherwise. But I'll dig in deeper from there, thanks!