# Pass the output of tail -f to a script

Tags: bash, shell-script

If I run tail -f /var/log/mail.log then it will sit there and follow (-f) mail.log as new lines are added to the file. Unfortunately the initial invocation causes it to print out the last ten lines before it continues to add them as the file changes. I just initially want the last line followed by the next ones, one by one, as they are added. How would I do that?

Having done that how would I redirect its output to a Bash Shell Script that takes each line as it is produced by tail -f and processes its content to do 'something else?

At the moment my 'something else' is

```
echo "Finding instances from blockstr.txt"

BLOCKDB=/home/pi/blockstr.txt
IPS=$(grep -Ev "^#" $BLOCKDB)
for i in $IPS
do
   grep $i /var/log/mail.log | grep -v opendkim | grep -E -o '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' | grep -v '^0' >> block.lst
done
#cat censys.txt >> block.lst
#cat imeas.txt >> block.lst
#cat intcens.txt >> block.lst
#cat iran.txt >> block.lst
iptables -S  | grep DROP | sed 's/^.\{12\}//' | sed 's/.\{11\}$//' > iptab.lst
sort -u block.lst > block.srt
sort -u iptab.lst > iptab.srt
comm -23 block.srt iptab.srt > diff.srt

echo "Blocking IP addresses..."
BLOCKDB=/home/pi/diff.srt
IPS=$(grep -Ev "^#" $BLOCKDB)
for i in $IPS
do
    echo "Adding " $i
    iptables -A INPUT -s $i -j DROP 
done
echo "done."

rm block.lst block.srt iptab.lst iptab.srt diff.srt
```

My apologies if that does not format correctly (got there, almost) however for each string in blockstr.txt it scans through mail.log line by line looking for instances and extracts the IP addresses then adds them to IPTables to block the miscreants.

It works as well as I might hope but it would be nice to have it continually do so in the background. Using tail -f to wake it up and feed it a new line seems like a way to do this rather than placing it in a cron job and hammering mail.log every 1s to catch the 60 attempted logins per second idiots.

Thanks for any help.

Just to confuse further my closest guessed prototype would be something like a pipe where I do

tail -f (one line only) /var/log/mail.log | ./blockstrings.sh

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Testing. Excuse me whilst I go through multiple broken things.

Comment: You may want to look into [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify). You also may want to look at this [question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331192/inotifywatch-continue-watch-after-file-rotation)

Comment: tail -n 0 -f /var/log/mail.log seems to work but computer says no to cat oneline.txt | ./blocktail ./blocktail burp says burp? blocktail.sh is echo $1   ?

Comment: At `> iptab.lst` you create an empty file and then 2 lines later at `sort -u iptab.lst` you try to sort the contents of that empty file. You should copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about. Also see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) and please format your code with indenting to make it more legible.

Comment: Thanks. DeGlobbed and now has a #!/bin/bash

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the spot as well. Now it is >> iptab.lst to append. That assumes that what I think I was trying to do does what I wanted it to do. I guess I should check again. Otherwise and sorry to dissapoint (I shall leave that misspelling there) I am not going to get into capitalisation and indentation. My brane literally cannot cope with what, to me, is terminally broken.

Comment: And Yes > iptab.lst was wrong >> iptab.lst looks better assuming the whole point was to prevent the addition of duplicates to iptables. Again. Thanks for the spot.

Comment: Almost exactly ten years ago, I started my own log scanning and blocking project for my own use called [txrban](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txrban/tree).  It's still running today. It has modules for Apache, Exim mail logs and SSH (auth.log).  The TXR language has built-in tail streams that follow growing/rotating files.  txrban works in real time. It bans addresses and unbans after different durations depending on score on a point scale.

Comment: hmmm, looks like you are trying to recreate fail2ban yourself - is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Per  `blocktail.sh is echo $1`. $1 refers to a command-line argument. Data coming from a pipe arrives on stdin, not on the command line. You read that with `read -r var`, or have a command read it (e.g `nl -ba` to show it went through the lnumber-lines command).

Answer (score 2):

`tail` outputs the last ten lines of the file by default, but there is an option `-n` to change that. It is not an error to ask for more lines than are present in the file.

The `-n` option takes an integer line count. Unsigned or negative values count back from the end of the file. Explicit positive values count from the start of the file, the first line being numbered `+1`. (This can be useful to skip header lines, for example.)

So `tail -n 0 -f myFile` will show only additions to the original file, and continue to wait for them. Additions are checked for every second (there is an option to change this also.)

To show the entire original file, and then wait for any additions, use:

`tail -n +1 -f myFile`

Some versions of `tail` also accept a numeric option directly, like `tail -5` or `tail +5`, but that is non-POSIX.

The output from `tail` to a pipe will be line-buffered. However, whatever is reading that pipe may not flush its own output, so there may be delays in the output of those results.

Comment: Thanks. This part of it works but looking elsewhere I get the impression that I cannot pass its output to a script for postprocessing. At best I can append its output, >>, to a file and that gets me back to square 1.

Comment: @Per  Your impression from elsewhere is wrong. A pipe connects the stdout of one process to the stdin of another. Try something in one terminal like `touch myLog; tail -n 0 myLog | nl -ba`, and in another terminal `for (( j = 1; j <= 20; j++ )); do date '+%T.%N'; sleep 1.3; done >> myLog`. You will see the appended lines appear at intervals, with timestamps, being sequentially numbered by `nl`.

Comment: @Per  In case that is unclear: the `for` loop just emulates your process that is appending to the log file as is. The `nl -ba` demonstrates that your script (in that position) would also be able to read additions to the log as they happen, with no need for any intermediate file.